# org.testng.TestNGException: Method tearDown requires 1 parameters but 0 were supplied in the @Configuration annotation

Tags: cucumber, testng

I am not able to understand what is required as parameter, can anyone help me with this.
**I have written below code:-**

```
 @Test(groups = "cucumber", description = "Runs Cucumber Feature", dataProvider = "features")
    public void feature(CucumberFeatureWrapper cucumberFeature) throws Exception {
        testNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(cucumberFeature.getCucumberFeature());
 }

@AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void tearDown(Scenario scenario) {
    scenario.write("Finished Scenario"); 
    if (scenario.isFailed()) {      
    String screenshotName = scenario.getName().replaceAll(" ", "_");
        try {
            File sourcePath =((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            File destinationPath = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/Screenshots/" + screenshotName + ".png");                
            Files.copy(sourcePath, destinationPath); 
            Reporter.addScreenCaptureFromPath(destinationPath.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
        } 
        driver.close();
    }   
    }
```

**And I am getting below error:-**

> FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod tearDown
>   org.testng.TestNGException:  Method tearDown requires 1 parameters but
>   0 were supplied in the @Configuration annotation.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass a `Cucumber Scenario` object to a `TestNg` configuration method. The `AfterMethod` will be called by `TestNg` and will not be able to inject the `Scenario` object. For a list of objects that are injected automatically refer to this - http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection

Either use the `After` annotation of Cucumber and pass the `Scenario` object.

```
@cucumber.api.java.After
public void tearDown(Scenario scenario)
```

Or use the `AfterMethod` of TestNg and pass the `ITestResult` object.

```
@org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod
public void tearDown(ITestResult result)
```

Comment: I tried with  " @After
public void tearDown(ITestResult result) " but code not running. checked with syso. now its not giving error but not running this code also.

Comment: You got the combination wrong... Use one of the two i mentioned in the answer

Comment: @priyankashaw - Please accept the answer provided, if it helped (I have edited the answer to add the fully qualified package names for the annotation)